# Translate in Araic language Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3.3, translate, language-package, arabic

**Product Name, Description and Layerd Navigation not Translate In Arabic Language.**

Using [Arabic Language Pack](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-arabic-language-pack.html) Install Language Pack.

> **1. Product Name**

[image: Product Name]

> **2. Product Description**

[image]

> **3. Layerd Navigation**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All words are not translated in language pack,

for custom added attribute and options you have to add those words in csv or need to add label in particular storeview

Comment: Means translate all product name manually ??

Comment: @RkRathod Yes those are dynamic data and need to be added in particular storeview level

Comment: any free extension available for this better than manually added??

Comment: use google translate but it will be not accurate https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-language-translator.html

Comment: as per client requirement create store for arabic language and translate all in arabic

Comment: @RkRathod sorry dear in that case you have to translate all that manually

Comment: ok bro thank you quick for response... :)

Answer (score 1):

@Murtuza Zabuawala answer is right.

For Custom text transalation, we can use **Google Sheet Transalate** option. This is super cool product introduced By **Google** itsef.

**Translate in Google Sheets**

[Translate in Google Sheets](https://jakemiller.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Translate-in-Google-Sheets.gif)

Comment: yes thats fine to not translate custom text but is there way to create that type of custom module ??

Comment: Sorry.. I don't know